# print awk output on the same line for some columns

Tags: html, awk

i have a file say test with the following output

```
vserver    share-name     path           acl 
TEST_SERVER TEST_SHARE_PATH /TEST/TESTSHAREPATH "test\testuser / Read","test\testuser1_R / Read","test\testuser2_RW / Change"
```

As the acl is big its coming in new line under vserver with proper alignment. But i want this to come in under acl like this

```
  vserver     share-name                path                acl 

 TEST_SERVER TEST_SHARE_PATH /TEST/TESTSHAREPATH  "test\testuser /Read",
                                                  "test\testuser1 R /Read",
                                                  "test\testuser1 RW / Change"
```

Kindly help

Comment: so what did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for FPAT and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR==1 {
    $1=$1
    print
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    next
}
{
    n  = split(gensub(/ ".*/,"",1),f,/ /)
    $1 = gensub(/[^"]+/,"",1,$1)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=n; j++) {
            printf "%s%s", f[j], OFS
        }
        print  $i
        delete f
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -s$'\t' -t
vserver      share-name       path                 acl
TEST_SERVER  TEST_SHARE_PATH  /TEST/TESTSHAREPATH  "test\testuser / Read"
                                                   "test\testuser1_R / Read"
                                                   "test\testuser2_RW / Change"
```

The above assumes there's no tabs in your input data. If there are then pick some other character for the OFS.

Comment: hi i am getting the below output like this vserver                   share-name       path                 acl
TEST_SERVER               TEST_SHARE_PATH  /TEST/TESTSHAREPATH
TEST_SHARE_PATH
/TEST/TESTSHAREPATH
"test\testuser
/
Read","test\testuser1_R
/
Read","test\testuser2_RW
/
Change"

Comment: You can't put formatted text in a comment so idk what you're trying to show me. The answer I posted produces the output you asked for given the input you posted, as shown in the answer. If it doesn't do what you want when you run it then either your real input doesn't match the sample in your question, or you made a mistake when copy/pasting the script from my answer, or you aren't running the awk variant stated as required in my answer, or the expected output you showed in your question doesn't match your real expected output.